# How to handle code dependency while deploying code?

Tags: deployment, ant, jenkins, ant-script

Here is a scenario what I have, I have two dev org (development, Testing), one Bitbucket repository and AWS EC2 that contain Jenkins with ANT migration tool.

I am not able to move all code in one build because of Salesforce dependency.

[image: Deployment Cycle]

How and where I put ANT/shell script that helps me out.

Comment: What do you mean by Salesforce dependency? Is it number of components you can add in a build or size of build?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal If we want to move code that contains apex class and custom object and target org is fresh then we cannot move it together.

Comment: we can, i did it hundred of times.

Comment: What error are you getting and why do you think they cannot be moved together?

Comment: Let give you an example: Object Name: `Abc__c` and apex class: `testClass`:
If `testClass` use `Abc__c` object and both are not in target org then if I deploy code together then Salesforce throw error `Abc__c` and it fields not found.

If I move first Objects and then Apex classes, Build become a success.

Comment: alternative - use a product like Gearset that can automatically deploy via CI from source to org - it checks dependencies for you and ensures before you deploy that you have included everything.  But Pranay is right - custom obj + apex class can be deployed together just fine - you are missing something else in your deployment package that the error message (see RedDevil) would illuminate